# Changing queryset definition causes app requests to queue up and performance to dip severely in Django web app (new relic output included)

Tags: python, django, performance, django-queryset

Dire performance situation: I have a web app where users leave messages and spectators upvote/downvote them. It's developed using Django. I have a `ListView` that populates the home page with users' latest messages.

My simple **models.py** contains:

```
class MessageVoteCountManager(models.Manager):
     def get_query_set(self):
          return super(MessageVoteCountManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value'))

class Message(models.Model):
     description = models.TextField()
     submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User) # django.contrib.auth.models user
     submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

     with_votes = MessageVoteCountManager()

class Vote(models.Model):
     voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
     message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
     value = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

In my **views.py**, I have a `ListView` to support the functionality I described in the first paragraph. It's basic skeleton is like so:

```
class MessageListView(ListView):
     model = Message
     queryset = Message.objects.order_by('-submitted_on')[:120]
     paginate_by = 10
```

Recently, I changed the queryset definition above to `queryset = Message.with_votes.order_by('submitted_on')[:120]` In other words, I annotated `votes` with each `message`, which is the **sum** of all `votes` a `message` instance has received. The moment this change went live, the following happened (new relic output). I *reverted* the commit at 6:27AM:

[image]

My best guess is that that I have half a million `messages` in my DB. Maybe once I change the `queryset` definition, requests queue up to recalculate all `messages` ever entered, and my app essentially suffers severely deprecated performance? I only want to apply this new `queryset` calculation to the latest **120** `messages` - hence I sliced the latest 120 after ordering them by date. This clearly didn't work.

How do I make sure the new `queryset` definition only applies to the **latest** `messages`, coming onwards from the point of changing the code? Something like: `(Message.objects.order_by('submitted'on')[:120]).with_votes` ?

Please ask me for more information if it's needed. My ultimate goal is to get better performance here.

Comment: You're saying `queryset = Message.with_votes.order_by('submitted_on')[:120]` ought correctly do what I'm intending?